# Snakemake: AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sample

Tags: python, wildcard, attributeerror, snakemake

```
InputFunctionException in line 226 of /users/troger50/projects/Rogers_SidersViralAnalysis_XXXX_20XX/preprocess_reads.smk:
Error:
  AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sample'
Wildcards:
  organism=0
Traceback:
  File "/users/troger50/projects/Rogers_SidersViralAnalysis_XXXX_20XX/preprocess_reads.smk", line 228, in <lambda>
```

I am new to snakemake and am beating my head against the wall trying to figure out a work around for something that should be so simple. Here is my pipeline:

```
configfile:"new_configure.yml"

rule all_run:
    input:
        multiqc = "quality_checks/multiqc/multiqc_report.html"


rule multiqc: #New
    input:
        fastqc= [expand(["quality_checks/fastqc/{organism}_r1_fastqc.html","quality_checks/fastqc/{organism}_r2_fastqc.html"], organism=organism) for sample, value in config["Samples"].items() for organism, j in value.items()],
        
    output:
        "quality_checks/multiqc/multiqc_report.html"
    params:
        in_put="quality_checks/"
    shell:
        """
           multiqc -d -dd 1 {params.in_put} -o quality_checks/multiqc/ --export
        """

rule Index:
    input:
        r1 = "data/raw/{sample}-{organism}_R1.fastq.gz"
    output:
        indexgz="data/raw/{sample}-{organism}-index1.fq.gz"
    log:
        Index_log="logs/{sample}-{organism}_Index.log"
    shell:
        """
            (zcat  {input.r1} |awk '{{if( (NR%4)==1){{ print $0; print substr($2,length($2)-20,10); print "+"; print "CCCCCCCCCC"}}}}' |gzip  > {output.indexgz}) 2> {log.Index_log}
        """

#Demultiplex Raw reads first
rule demultiplex_reads:
    input:
        r1="data/raw/{sample}-{organism}_R1.fastq.gz", 
        r2="data/raw/{sample}-{organism}_R2.fastq.gz",
        indexgz="data/raw/{sample}-{organism}-index1.fq.gz"
    output:
        r1 = "data/raw/demultiplexed/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r1.fq.gz",
        r2 = "data/raw/demultiplexed/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r2.fq.gz"
    params:
        index="data/raw/Index.txt",
    log:
        "logs/{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_deML.log"
    shell:
        """
            (/projects/luo_lab/deML/src/deML -o data/raw/demultiplexed/demultiplexed -i {params.index} -f  {input.r1}  -r {input.r2} -if1 {input.indexgz}) 2> {log}
        """

#Trim addapters from raw reads
rule bbduk_adp:
    input: 
        r1 = "data/raw/demultiplexed/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r1.fq.gz",
        r2 = "data/raw/demultiplexed/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r2.fq.gz"

    output:
        r1 = temp("data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r1.fq.gz"),
        r2 = temp("data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r2.fq.gz")

    log:
        "logs/{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_bbduk_adp.log"
    shell:
        """
            (/projects/luo_lab/bbmap/bbduk.sh ordered in1={input.r1} in2={input.r2} \
                out1={output.r1} \
                out2={output.r2} \
                ref=/projects/luo_lab/bbmap/resources/adapters.fa ktrim=r k=23 mink=11 hdist=1 tpe tbo) 2> {log}
        """

# Further trimming step to increase the quality
rule bbduk_qal:
    input: 
        r1 = "data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r1.fq.gz",
        r2 = "data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r2.fq.gz"

    output:
        r1 = "data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r1.fq.gz",
        r2 = "data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_r2.fq.gz"

    log:
        # "logs/{sample}-{organism}_{fraction}_bbduk_qal.log"
    shell:
        """
            (/projects/luo_lab/bbmap/bbduk.sh ordered in1={input.r1} in2={input.r2} \
                out1={output.r1} \
                out2={output.r2} \
                ref=/projects/luo_lab/bbmap/resources/adapters.fa k=27 hdist=1 qtrim=rl trimq=17 cardinality=t mingc=0.05 maxgc=0.95) 2> {log}
        """

rule merge_clean_reads:
    input:
        r1 = lambda wildcards : [f"data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{wildcards.sample}-{wildcards.organism}_{fraction}_r1.fq.gz" for fraction in config["Samples"][wildcards.sample][wildcards.organism]],
        r2 = lambda wildcards : [f"data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{wildcards.sample}-{wildcards.organism}_{fraction}_r2.fq.gz" for fraction in config["Samples"][wildcards.sample][wildcards.organism]]

    output:
        r1="data/processed/clean_reads/merged/merged_{organism}_r1.fq.gz",
        r2="data/processed/clean_reads/merged/merged_{organism}_r2.fq.gz"
    shell:
        """
            cat  {input.r1} > {output.r1}
            cat  {input.r1} > {output.r2}
        """

# Evalutate the quality of the trimmed reads
rule fastqc:
    output:
        ["quality_checks/fastqc/{organism}_r1_fastqc.html","quality_checks/fastqc/{organism}_r2_fastqc.html"]
    input:  
        ["data/processed/clean_reads/merged/merged_{organism}_r1.fq.gz","data/processed/clean_reads/merged/merged_{organism}_r2.fq.gz"]
    log:
        "logs/merged_{organism}_fastqc_clean.log"
    shell:
        """
            (fastqc -o quality_checks/fastqc/ {input:q}) 2> {log}
        """
```

and here is my config file:

```
ROOT: "."
Samples:
    day7-DO-0-12C: 
        0:
            - "1-6"
            - "7"
            - "8"
            - "9"
            - "10-12"
        viral:
            - "1-6"
            - "7"
            - "8"
            - "9"
            - "10-12"

    day7-DO-0-13C: 
        0:
            - "1-5"
            - "6"
            - "7"
            - "8"
            - "9-12"
        viral: 
            - "1-6"
            - "7"
            - "8"
            - "9"
            - "10-12"
```

The issue is with rule merge_clean_reads. In the input I am using a lamdba function and calling wild cards "sample" and "organism". The error is obvious as I have not defined "sample" as a wildcard. But, I not sure where I should define it as the output of merge_clean_reads should only consider the "organism" wildcard and there should only be four output files: merged_0_r1.fq.gz, merged_0_r2.fq.gz, merged_viral_r1.fq.gz, and merged_viral_r2.fq.gz. I know this has got to be an easy fix, but I havent been able to fix it lol. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your samples `day7-DO-0-12C` and `day7-DO-0-13C`, and the organisms, `0` and `viral`?

Comment: Yep, thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the error is because the wildcards available in a rule are dictated by those in the *output* file.  That rule simply has no `sample` wildcard to use in your input function.

Instead, you need a map between an organism and all the samples and fractions that belong to it.  You have this information in your config, but not in the correct order.  If you can, I would consider reorganizing your config hierarchy.  Otherwise, the code below will build the map you need:

```
# basically reverse the first two levels of your config['Samples']
# these names are verbose for clarity, you may have better intuition about what they mean
organisms_samples_fractions = {}
for sample, organism_fraction in config["Samples"].items():
    for organism, fractions in organism_fraction.items():
        if organism not in organisms_samples_fractions:
            organisms_samples_fractions[organisms] = {}
        organisms_samples_fractions[organisms][sample] = fractions


def merge_clean_reads_input(wildcards):
    # now you have to deal with some fractions possibly not present in all samples
    # otherwise i would use an expand
    return {
        'r1': [
            f"data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{wildcards.organism}_{fraction}_r1.fq.gz",
            for sample in organisms_samples_fractions[wildcards.organism]
            for fraction in organisms_samples_fractions[wildcards.organism][sample]
              ],
        'r2': [
            f"data/processed/clean_reads/demultiplexed_{sample}-{wildcards.organism}_{fraction}_r2.fq.gz",
            for sample in organisms_samples_fractions[wildcards.organism]
            for fraction in organisms_samples_fractions[wildcards.organism][sample]
              ],
            }


rule merge_clean_reads:
    input:
        unpack(merge_clean_reads_input)

    output:
        r1="data/processed/clean_reads/merged/merged_{organism}_r1.fq.gz",
        r2="data/processed/clean_reads/merged/merged_{organism}_r2.fq.gz"
    shell:
        """
            cat  {input.r1} > {output.r1}
            cat  {input.r2} > {output.r2}  # NOTE this was input.r1
        """
```

Comment: Thank you! Ill try that out and see how it goes. You also said:"If you can, I would consider reorganizing your config hierarchy." What would you change about the hierarchy?

Comment: I just meant it may make more sense to order the levels in your config as organisms, samples, fractions instead of samples, organisms, fractions, but that would depend on the experimental details.